# How to get previous month date and year in java

Tags: java, calendar

First i set month and year then i want previous month and year not current month. now i getting which month set on calender that month only

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class PrevMonth 
{
    private static String prev_day_str;
    private static String prev_month_str;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat prev_day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        Calendar calendar   = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);

        calendar .add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);      //subtracting a month
        SimpleDateFormat prev_month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        SimpleDateFormat prev_year = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
        prev_day_str = prev_month.format(new Date(calendar .getTimeInMillis()));
        prev_month_str = prev_year.format(new Date(calendar .getTimeInMillis()));

        System.out.println(prev_day_str+" "+prev_month_str);
    }

}
```

Result:
01 2015
need for 12 2014

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

actually sets the month to February.

For January you need to use 0, ie.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
```

Comment: but 1 also getting dynamic then how?

Comment: calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2); Output: 2015 02 but need 2015 01

Answer (score 0):

You start by initialize the calendar to February instead of January :

```
    public class PrevMonth  {
    private static String prev_day_str;
    private static String prev_month_str;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat prev_day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        Calendar calendar   = Calendar.getInstance();
        // 0 for January
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
        // -1 for substruct
        calendar .add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);      //subtracting a month
        SimpleDateFormat prev_month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        SimpleDateFormat prev_year = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
        prev_day_str = prev_month.format(new Date(calendar .getTimeInMillis()));
        prev_month_str = prev_year.format(new Date(calendar .getTimeInMillis()));

        System.out.println(prev_day_str+" "+prev_month_str);
    }

}
```

Comment: calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
Output:
2015 02 but need 2015 01

Comment: remember that 2 means 3/2015 , so u get 2/2015 after substruct 1 month - look at the comment inside the code

Comment: so java calender start with 0 end with 11 for months

Comment: almost true ... actually its circular ... ( 12 means 1/2016, 24 means 1/2017 ... etc. )

Comment: but i using month is 12 but getting 2014 12

Comment: make sure you save your code before running it ... i just try now and if i put 12 : the end-result ( after substruction ) is 12/2015. if i put 24 : then the end-result (after substruction ) is 12/2016. consider it that way ( when Calendar.YEAR is 2015, then Calendar.MONTH is the offset from January/2015. means that 0 is January itself, 1 is the next (Feb) 12 is 12 monthes ahead ( January/2016 ) etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96114/discussion-between-jayakumar-and-chenchuk).